# Catching the "Open with..." in Visual Basic 2010 Express?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm creating a small program for viewing images. However, the whole idea is that it could be used as a default for image-files. So, how can I catch the file, that user tries to open? Path to file is enough. Here's an example:

User right-clicks an image and chooses "My Program" from the "Open with..."-menu. Now I need to see, what file the user wants to see.

I'm an absolute beginner in VB, so please be patient with me =D

Martti Laine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a file association ([MSFT KB Article 307859](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307859) for details how to do this manually), then your application will be started with the file set as one of the arguments.

You can use `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` to get those arguments.